# Running tests using ScalaFutures in ScalaTest throws IllegalStateException from time to time

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, scalatest, slick-3.0

When running tests using scalatest I get an IllegalStateException from time to time:

> The future returned an exception of type:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException, with message: Cannot initialize
>   ExecutionContext; AsyncExecutor already shut down.

I'm using ScalaTest 2.2.6 in conjunction with Play framework 2.4 and Slick 3.1. Tests look as follows:

```scala
class FooDaoImplSpec
  extends PlaySpec
  with TestConfiguration
  with OneAppPerSuite
  with ScalaFutures
  with IntegrationPatience {

  override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .loadConfig(testConfig)
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .bindings(bind[FooDao].to[FooDaoImpl])
    .build

  "FooDao#findAll" must {
    "return a result set with the length of 3" in {
      val fooDao = app.injector.instanceOf[FooDao]
      val result: Future[Seq[FooModel]] = fooDao.findAll()
      whenReady(result) { r =>
        r must have length (3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`fooDao` in the example above uses Slick to query the database. Maybe it is also worth to mention that `FooDaoImpl` uses Play's internal execution context (`play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext`).

I'm really a bit stuck here. As I already mentioned the exception is randomly thrown in one of my test suites but only from time to time.

Has anyone else encountered the same issue before? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I figured it out. I accidentally had my tests ran in `parallelExecution` set to `true`. The following sbt settings fixed the issue for me:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
fork in Test := true
```